# A maximal inequality on distance to median, so called Lévy's inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, inequality

## Problem

(Kai Lai Chung, *A Course in Probability Theory*, section 5.3, ex6) Suppose $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$ are $n$ independent random variables, and $S_j:=X_1+\dotsb+X_j,S_j^0:=S_j-m_0(S_j)$, where $m_0(S_j)$ is a median of $S_j$. Then we have $\mathbb P\{\max_{1\le j\le n}\lvert S_j^0\rvert>\epsilon\}\le3\mathbb P\{\lvert S_n^0\rvert>\epsilon/2\}$ for $\epsilon>0$.

It's so-called Lévy inequality, but slightly different from [this](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Levy_inequality).

## Remark

By a median of a probability measure $\mu$, we mean a $c$ (not uniquely determined) such that $\mu(-\infty,c]\ge1/2,\mu[c,+\infty)\ge1/2$. A median of a random variable is a median of its probability distribution measure.

## Thought

Just as any other maximal inequality, maybe we should partition the probability space. Set $\Lambda_k=\{\max_{1\le j<k}S_j^0\le\epsilon;S_k^0>\epsilon\}$, then by stochastic independence,
\begin{align}
\mathbb P\{S_n^0>\epsilon/2\}&=\sum_k\mathbb P\{\Lambda_k;S_n^0>\epsilon/2\}\\&\ge\sum_k\mathbb P\{\Lambda_k;S_n^0-S_k^0>-\epsilon/2\}\\&=\sum_k\mathbb P(\Lambda_k)\mathbb P\{S_n^0-S_k^0>-\epsilon/2\}
\end{align}
And we have $S_n^0-S_k^0>-\epsilon/2\iff S_n-S_k>-\epsilon+m_0(S_n)-m_0(S_k)$. However, I don't see any reason that the probability of it is no less than $1/3$.

Any idea? Thanks!